# How to specify rollback in Spring using wildcards?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-jdbc

I have following code in Spring -

```
<tx:advice id="transactionAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException" no-rollback-for="java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException"
                timeout="30" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```

This configuration will rollback for `DataAccessException` and all its sub-exceptions. i.e. the exception hierarchy is rolled back. However I want to be able to rollback a set of exceptions (not belonging to same hierarchy). Is it possible to write something like -

```
<tx:advice id="transactionAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="org.springframework.*" no-rollback-for="java.lang.*"
                timeout="30" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```

I have tried the above code but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use wildcards, but

```
   <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="org.springframework" no-rollback-for="java.lang" />
```

will do that you want. Match is positive if the `Exception` class name contains the pattern.

Comment: How do I force close a transaction using rollback?

Answer (score 0):

Spring typically uses plain substring as exception matching pattern.

For example, RollbackRuleAttribute javadoc

> NB: Consider carefully how specific the pattern is, and whether to
>   include package information (which is not mandatory). For example,
>   "Exception" will match nearly anything, and will probably hide other
>   rules. "java.lang.Exception" would be correct if "Exception" was meant
>   to define a rule for all checked exceptions. With more unusual
>   exception names such as "BaseBusinessException" there's no need to use
>   a fully package-qualified name.

so you can try to use `"org.springframework."`. However it doesn't seem that this is documented, Spring documentation only mentions that *rollback-for* has comma-delimeted format.

> *rollback-for* Exception(s) that trigger rollback; comma-delimited. For example, com.foo.MyBusinessException,ServletException